# Stress tensor with indices in two-dimensions

Tags: conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am interested in the stress tensor of a CFT_2 living on a conformally flat background, say,
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{1}{x^2}(-dt^2 + dx^2).
\end{equation}

What if I want to know the stress tensor in the (tt) and (xx) components? I can find endless resources on the properties of the stress tensor in 2d. But I am a simple guy and just want $<T^{xx}>$. Where do I even start to find this expression?

Some sources also give it in terms of Virasoro generators in a holomorphic and anti-holomorphic part. Some sources also go to the half plane, $\omega$ and give you $T(\omega)$. But this in terms of the Schwarszian derivative has no components, so I don't know how to translate it into $T^{xx}$.

Any ideas on how to get $<T^{xx}>$? It feels like this should be a standard result but I really struggle to find it.

Edit: For instance, [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0405152.pdf) Cardy and Calabrese compute $T(\omega)$ on a flat background. But that has no indices and is thus not a tensor?

Comment: $T^{xx}$ of what? Which theory are you working with?

Comment: of a CFT$_2$ on an AdS$_2$ background @Prahar.